# Need to add multiple filter in angular ui select

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter, angular-filters, angular-ui-select

Need to add multiple filter in `angular` uiselect2.

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <ui-select id="abc" ng-model="abc" multiple theme="bootstrap"  >
       <ui-select-match placeholder="Select abc..." class="ui-select-match">{{$item.name | capitalize}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices id= "abchoice" class="ui-select-choices" repeat="item in itemDetails| filter: $select.search ">
               <div id="selected_{{item}}" ng-bind-html="item .name | capitalize | highlight: $select.search" style="padding: 0px; "></div>
         </ui-select-choices>
     </ui-select>

</div>
```

I have

```
itemDetails=["a","b","c"]
orderItem=["c"]
```

And I need to filter it by `filter: $select.search` also by orderItem. How to add this custom filter in ui-select?

IN dropdown I shoud get only a, b, i should filter c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try something like that**

```
var app = angular.module('demo', ['ui.select']);
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.itemDetails = ['a','b','c'];
  $scope.orderItem = {};
  $scope.orderItem.items = ['a','b']; // by default selected items

});
```

**In your view**

```
<ui-select multiple ng-model="orderItem.items" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;">
   <ui-select-match placeholder="Select order item...">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item in itemDetails | filter:$select.search">
      {{item}}
    </ui-select-choices>
 </ui-select>
  <p>Selected: {{orderItem.items}}</p>
```

[Plunker 1](https://embed.plnkr.co/8VFoBo6MdRNL9HjiSxUQ/)

**Exclude an Item using a filter**

**Controller:**

```
 'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('demo', ['ui.select']);
    app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.itemDetails = ['a','b','c'];
      $scope.orderItem = {};
      $scope.orderItem.items = null;
    });
  // filter to exclude a value/item
  app.filter('Exclude', function() {
      return function( items) {
        var filtered = [];
        angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
          if(item!='c'){
            filtered.push(item);
          }
        });
        return filtered;
      };          
 });
```

**View:**

```
<p>Selected: {{orderItem.items}}</p>
  <ui-select ng-model="orderItem.items" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select order item...">{{$select.selected}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item in itemDetails | Exclude |  filter:$select.search">
      {{item}}
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

[Plunker 2](https://embed.plnkr.co/LFBPpWLhVdfCyAp3aYFg/)

Comment: thnaks for reply... but i need to add filter.. i should not get c in my droupdown.,, thats my question. @MMK

Comment: can u help me!@MMK

Comment: custom filter is required to exclude the object you dont need.

Comment: @mammam check the updated answer, hopefully it will help you

Answer (score 0):

If you need to filter your `orderItem` from the list, then remove them to this list.

You should have 3 lists:

- allItems (To have all items stored somewhere)
- orderItems
- itemsInSelect

When you select one item from the itemsInSelect, then add it to the orderItems and remove it from the itemsInSelect.

Is that you want ?

Comment: Sometime, take the problem in another way is the solution ;)